# custom tableviewcell dynamic height not updating as per constraints (with programmatically autolayout)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have a custom uitableviewcell in app, I am trying to update its length dynamically based on its subviews (labels) contents.

but it's not working.

find related code as below.

```
class TransactionTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{


    private lazy var dateLabel: UILabel = {
        let datelabel = UILabel()
        datelabel.textColor = .label
        datelabel.backgroundColor = .red
        datelabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
        datelabel.numberOfLines = 0
        datelabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return datelabel
    }()

another method in same class:

 func setupDefaultUI(){
        self.contentView.addSubview(dateLabel)
}

 override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setupDefaultUI()
        buildConstraints()
    }

 override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupDefaultUI()
        buildConstraints()
    }

 func buildConstraints(){

        let marginGuide = self.contentView

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            dateLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.topAnchor)
            ,
            dateLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.leadingAnchor),
            dateLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.trailingAnchor),
            dateLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 1.0)
            ,

            dateLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.bottomAnchor)
  ])
    }
```

and inside viewcontroller file:

```
 private lazy var transactionTableView: UITableView = {
        let tableview = UITableView.init()
        tableview.backgroundView = nil
        tableview.backgroundColor = .clear
        tableview.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableview.estimatedRowHeight = 300
        return tableview
    }()
```

and in viewdidload:

```
    transactionTableView.dataSource = Objdatasource 
        transactionTableView.delegate = Objdelegate

        transactionTableView.register(TransactionTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifiers.transactionCell)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remove this

```
dateLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 1.0)
```

Comment: i have removed as per your feedback but it didn't worked. @Sh_Khan

Answer (score 0):

In [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dynamically-change-tableview-cell-height-in-swift) tutorial (which I recently followed and worked for me), there is a function you are missing there:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

Comment: I thought we don't need to write above function because i have specified below code :    tableview.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableview.estimatedRowHeight = 300

Comment: still i have include function as per your comment. but still it didn't worked.